# Error: 'The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.'

Tags: google-api, google-play

I'm asking this question again because existing solutions are not working in 2022.

1. Users give their package name in an input URL.
2. I have Oauth on my website.
3. I get auth token and refresh token from here and send a request to the following API.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/your_package_name/reviews?
access_token=your_auth_token
```

I get the following error

```
I get the project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.'
```

Is this happening because I have not asked for any scope in Oauth?

Is there any way I can make getting reviews as simple as possible for users? Like after Oauth, users can immediately look at their ratings for this week.

[image]
I have switched on all these on play.google.com/console.